# C++ SetProcessAffinityMask

Tags: c++

Всем привет! Есть такая функция:

> BOOL SetProcessAffinityMask ( 
> HANDLE hProcess,                //
> дескриптор процесса 
> **DWORD_PTR** dwProcessAffinityMask // маска
> родственного процесса 
> );

`DWORD_PTR` - это вроде `ulong`, т.е. 32 бита, значит только 32 ядра можно назначить. Но в документации говорится, что проблемы могут возникнуть, если процессоров больше 64.
Отсюда вопрос:

- как с помощью этой функции назначить больше 32 процессоров?
- есть ли аналоги этой функции, позволяющие назначить до 64 процессоров?

Comment: В [документации](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types) сказано, что `#if defined(_WIN64)`, то это `__int64`.

Comment: `DWORD_PTR` имеет размер указателя, т.е. на 64-битной системе можно раздать на 64 процессора. Для распределения по большему количеству процессоров есть процессорные группы.

Comment: @tocic а для этого надо явно добавлять что-то вроде: `SetProcessAffinityMask(thread, DWORD_PTR(uint64(1) << affinity))` или если передать `uint64` оно само подхватится?

Comment: @JohnDoe невнимательно прочитал: там `unsigned __int64`, а не просто `__int64`. Можете делать явный каст, можете не делать, если есть соответствующие преобразования. Примеры использования функции можете посмотреть [тут](https://sourcegraph.com/search?q=context:global+SetProcessAffinityMask%5C%28%5B%5E%2C%5D%2B%2C+lang:c%2B%2B&patternType=regexp), например.